# How can I remove the error state from a <input matInput>?

Tags: typescript, angular-material2

I have a `changePasswordForm: FormGroup` which I want to display empty and without any error states after the user changed the password.

After the REST call returns I also do the following:

```
this.changePasswordForm.reset();
// this.changePasswordForm.setErrors(null); // <-- same result
this.changePasswordForm.setErrors({required: null});
this.changePasswordForm.updateValueAndValidity();
```

However, all `input` fields remain in the error state.

How can I remove the error state from a `<input matInput>`?